# No Parameters in Net class even after inheriting from nn.Module

Tags: parameters, deep-learning, pytorch, torch

For some reason, my Class Net has no parameters, even though i have imported everything correctly., its still showing that net has no parameters or attributes and even on printing net its just prints empty list. Can anyone tell me what's wrong ?

```
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class Net(nn.Module):
def ___init__(self):
    super(Net, self).__init__()
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(784, 64)
    self.fc2 = nn.Parameter(nn.Linear(64, 64))
    self.fc3 = nn.Parameter(nn.Linear(64, 64))
    self.fc4 = nn.Parameter(nn.Linear(64, 10))
    
def forward(self, x):
    x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
    x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
    x = F.relu(self.fc3(x))
    x = self.fc4(x)
    return F.log_softmax(x, dim=1)

net = Net()
print(net)
print(list(net.parameters()))
```

Output:

```
Net()
[]
```

Comment: P.S. Even tried wrapping nn.Linear in nn.Parameters but in vain. Also, tried this in Colab but still not good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code

```
def ___init__(self):
```

you're using three underscores before `init`, use two: `__init__`.

Comment: Thanks dude, never expected a typo would cause this much issue.